# Scroll Reveal Blur Stuck On

Tags: jquery, html, css

Hi i made a simple scroll reveal so that the div below the initial div unblurs as it's shown, it works perfectly in jsfiddle but when I put it into my site it doesn't work... everything is literally the same only my site is using jquery version 3.2.1 min js,

If anyone can let me know why it wouldn't work in my site but does on JS fiddle would be great!

```js
$(window).scroll(function() {
    var revealBlur = 10 - Math.floor($(window).scrollTop() / 15);
    if (revealBlur < 0) { revealBlur = 0; }
    $('#content2').css({
      '-webkit-filter': 'blur('+revealBlur+'px)'
    });  
});
```

```css
body {
  margin: 0;
}
.content2 {
    width: 100%;
    height: 300px;
    position: sticky;
    bottom: 0;
    z-index: -1;
    background: url(https://placekitten.com/1200/800) no-repeat;
}
.content1 {
    width: 100%;
    height: 300px;
    position: relative;
    background: url(https://placekitten.com/1200/800) no-repeat;
}

#content2 {
  -webkit-filter: blur(15px);
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.2.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="content1" class="content1"></div>
<div id="content2" class="content2">
</div>
```

https://jsfiddle.net/joshtrose/vr1n8ty7/1/

The jQuery file I'm using

```
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.2.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
```

Comment: Everything works just fine for me in chrome, both here on SO and on jsfiddle. I would ask you to look at the console log corresponding to your site, and see if it reports any errors.

Comment: Yea works on here with the same jquery version i'm using on my site but on my site the bottom div is always 15px burred no matter how much I scroll.

Answer (score 0):

`position:sticky` is not very well supported by chrome.
you can check these from Can I Use,

[Here](https://caniuse.com/#search=position%3A%20sticky)

According to Can I use, Till version 55, it didn't supported at all and after 56 to current version, it has Limited support on chrome.

Comment: I tried with sticky and without and same problem, sticky is just to show exactly how it's implemented but for some reason my site just shows the div fully blurred at all times, no matter what setting the blur is at, currently set to start at 15 but on my site it's just always 15px blurred.

Comment: what'll happen when you try this on firefox?

Comment: also doesn't work, must be something with my code, but no errors and exactly the same code as in the demo just more stuff in the div... confusing.

Comment: it works similar to jsfiddle when you click Run code snippet on at the bottom of the question. check if you have any extensions in your browser like adblocks or similar and try with them disabled. could be JS running blocked somehow.

Comment: Fixed it... was in the wrong order in my .js file, moved the jquery further up the order and now works, thanks for the help, good to know it was definitely my code.

Comment: you should always include jquery first, then bootstrap(if you have ), then your custom scripts. glad to see you got it fixed anyhow. also sometimes there may be problems with $ and you can try replacing it with jQuery Ex: $(".classname")  with jQuery(".classname")

Answer (score 0):

can you please try adding your code in domContentLoaded event,
eg:

```
window.addEventListener("DOMContentLoaded", function(){
   $(window).scroll(function() {
     var revealBlur = 10 - Math.floor($(window).scrollTop() / 15);
     if (revealBlur < 0) { revealBlur = 0; }
       $('#content2').css({
       '-webkit-filter': 'blur('+revealBlur+'px)'
     });
   });
```

});

Hope this helps

Comment: Still not working, checked for dom errors in chrome as well and nothing showing up, definitely for some reason this jquery isn't activating because there's no changes looking at the google inspector as I scroll, would expect the "blur:" value activate and change as I scroll but doesn't even activate.

Answer (score -1):

Moved the jquery code below closer to the top of .js file and now works.

```
window.addEventListener("DOMContentLoaded", function(){
   $(window).scroll(function() {
     var revealBlur = 10 - Math.floor($(window).scrollTop() / 15);
     if (revealBlur < 0) { revealBlur = 0; }
       $('#content2').css({
       '-webkit-filter': 'blur('+revealBlur+'px)'
     });
   });
});
```